# How i can obtain all the post meta for a specific post as an array?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php $fields = get_post_custom($ID); ?>
```

This will fetch the custom fields (`$key => $value`) for `$ID` in to the array `$fields`.

I want ALL the fields (both custom & standard WP fields) associated with the `$ID` in one `array $fields_all`. How to do this in a simpler way?....is there a single function available in WP?

Answer (score 4):

there is no single function you can use but you can create your own something like:

```
function get_all_post_fields($post_id){
    $p['standard'] = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
    $p['meta'] = get_post_custom($post_id);
    return $p;
}
```

then once you have this in your functions.php file  you can use it:

```
$fields_all = get_all_post_fields($ID);
```

### Update:

If you have just the title then i have a simple function i use a lot to get the post id by the title:

```
function get_post_ID_by_title($page_title) {
    global $wpdb;
        $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type='post'", $page_title ));
        if ( $post_id )
            return post_id;
    return false;
}
```

usage: `$post_id = get_post_ID_by_title("this is my title");`